# stuck in bootloader with usb debug off

Tags: usb, bootloader, usb-debugging

i am stuck in bootloop with no recov.img installed.
My usb debug is off too.how enble usb debug in bootloader ?

Comment: Please help me i am stuck very bad

Comment: My boot loader is not unlocked yet

Comment: You don't need USB Debugging to be enabled when you are booted to the bootloader.  What make/model phone is this?  What have you tried?  My suggestion would be to flash the stock images to your device.

Answer (score 1):

First, unlock you bootloader. With your phone in the bootloader, connect it to you computer via USB. Download fastboot (just google "fastboot download"). Then open CMD or terminal, depending on what OS you have on your computer. Run `fastboot oem unlock`.

Then download TWRP, found [here](https://twrp.me). Make sure you chose the right device (whatever device you have). Download that. At your command line run `fastboot flash recovery path/to/twrp.img`

Comment: For newer devices, OEM debugging has to be enabled in a booted OS first before you could use that fastboot command. Since OP is now stuck, there's no way he could've enabled that if he didn't previously. Waiting on OP's feedback about this part.